# Query on opening and closing files in C

Tags: c, text-files

This isn't a given problem with my code but more rather a decent sized shortcut if this works.

In my C program I have a fair few files which have number values (Test 1, Test 2, etc) so I was wondering that in the clause:

```
fa = fopen("Test 02","r");
if (fa == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open defs\n");
    getch();
    exit(1);
}
do {
    ...
}
```

I could do something like:

```
fa = fopen("Test %d Definitions.txt","r",count);
if (fa == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open defs\n");
    getch();
    exit(1);
}
do {
    ...
}
count=count+1;
```

I've been thinking this because it would reduce a file selection code down a hell of a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the filename first

```
char filename[256];
snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "Test %d Definitions.txt", count);
fa=fopen(filename,"r");
..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` for that. `fopen` is not a variadic function. Its prototype is:

`FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode );`

Use `sprintf(filename, "Test %d Definitions.txt",count);`

Then do a `fopen(filename, "r");`